# Weighted logistic regression

Tags: statistics, regression

When we have a sample consisting of response variable has small number of 1 and large number of 0 (say 500 are 1 and 500000 are 0), is there a way to build a better logistic regression model using some methods? I googled and knew could put weights on the data but not so sure how. I am using R to build the model(glm()) so wonder if anyone could offer some guide.

Comment: What is the problem with the usual method? If it is telling you that the log-odds are highly negative in the whole range (i.e. the probabilities of $1$ are very small), this may be a reflection of reality

Comment: Because I think the data is a bit unbalanced?

Comment: Apart from the $1000:1$ ratio you can observe, what other reason do you have for thinking the data may be unbalanced?